# Junit 4 / Junit 5 JDK 11 JDK 17 versions and compatibility

Tags: java, junit4, junit5, java-11, java-17

Hi which version Junit4 supports JDK 11 ?
And which Minimum Version supports JDK 17  ?  Junit4 ? or just Junit5 ?

where i can find list of version compatibility Java 11 and Java 17

Answer (score 4):

JUnit4 first version is released at around 2006 ,very long before than the release date of JDK11 (25-Sept-2018). Considering that Java is backward compatible, meaning that you can use the library that is compiled with the older JDK with any newer JDK, Junit4 should work with any JDK that is released after 2006.

As for JUnit5, it requires at least Java 8 according to the [user guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-java-versions).

So in short, you do not need to worry about it as both version can work with JDK11 or JDK17.

On the other hand, simply use Junit5 if you are developing a new project. No idea, why you may need JUnit4.